# GIT: keep local file from repo without updating

Tags: git, gitlab, gitignore

We have a file in our Gitlab repo, a config file with base settings the team should use as a starting point.  When a new team member clones the repo, he sets it up locally with his own settings.

We keep forgetting and checking it back in (I may not notice it in a list of 100 files).

So, we want the virgin file to stay in the repo, everyone's local copy to stay local, and the local files to not get overwritten on pull.

Is this possible?  I have tried a simple gitignore entry, but it seems to then want to remove the file from the repo.  Unless I simply did something wrong.

The tram uses an assortment of git clients, including the command line.

Comment: `.gitignore` means don't include it in the repo. This might not be procedurally acceptable, but what about having a different name for the config in the repo (*e.g.*, `project.conf.master`), and when the user first clones the repo, they have to copy it over to the actual config file name (*e.g.*, `project.conf`)? And put the actual name, `project.conf`, in the `.gitignore` since it would then not need to be in the repo. That's the one they edit.

Comment: We might just try that, it seems simpler than other solutions